# AppStoreでリリース中のiPhoneアプリのクラッシュの原因を突き止めるための手立ては何かありませんか？

Tags: swift, xcode

お世話になります。

AppStoreでリリース中のiPhoneアプリで、ユーザーから「アプリが開かない」「落ちる」などのフィードバックがあるのですが、私の実機やXcodeのシュミレーターでは、その現象が再現できず、クラッシュの原因が特定できません。

このような場合に、クラッシュの原因を突き止めるための手立ては何かありますせんか？

何か、とっかかりとか、ヒントでも良いのですが。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: コメントの記載を回答に纏めました。

Answer (score 5):

**クラッシュした端末の特定**
`iTunesConnect`の`Appアナリティクス`から`メトリックス`>`クラッシュ数`を見て、
`デバイス`と`プラットフォームバージョ‌​ン`でフィルタをかけるとクラッシュした端末を特定できます。
もしOSや端末に偏りがあるのであれば、その端末特有の問題の可能性があるので対処のためにも実機を用意出来たら良いかと思います。

---

**クラッシュ位置の特定([クラッシュレポートの分析](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html)）**
Xcodeにある`Organizer`の`Crashes`では診断で「Appデベロッパと共有」を行っているユーザのログが見れます。
申請時のプロジェクトが残っていれば、プロジェクトを指定することでクラッシュ位置まで飛ぶ機能まで付いています。

Comment: ありがとうございます！試してみます！